# Dynamics CRM - Create a Plugin to add a new logical operator into the advanced find

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, advanced-search

I am trying to add a new option into the Advanced Find in Dynamics CRM 2011, yet am unable to find if there is a way to do this.

The reason is that I want to get the current user and then use one of their attributes to reduce the list of found items, for example The users list says they look after all the car sales for Texas, instead of showing all the sales in Texas for Cars and Vans I want to show just Cars.  However there is someone else who wants to look at the list and see all the sales of Cars and Vans, thus I can't set the owner - if that makes sense.

So I want to be able to do is add an option into the advanced find so I can say where all the cars are in the current users list of cars they are interested in.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a plugin or how to add extra options to the search window? Or, perhaps, how to design the query? A fellow programmer, @Daryl, had a similar question not that long ago - that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without creating a plugin... On the edit filter you select the object as a relational object, rather than the actual field. For example:

When you pick the field go to the "Related" section in the combo box:

[image: Select the Related section in the combo box.]

Once you have done this you can chain them back to the part that you want:

[image: Multiple Chained Items]

Thus there is actually no need to create a plugin just as long as all relationships are created etc.

Comment: Advanced Find provide functionality to construct any queries except aggregates.